# Join on max(T.<column>) including further information of T

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables

```
create table item( id int )
insert into item ( id ) values ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 )

create table itemstatus
(
    itemid int 
    , ts datetime
    , "status" int
)

insert into itemstatus ( itemid, ts, status ) values 
( 1, '2013-12-01T12:00:00.000', 1 ),
( 1, '2013-12-01T11:00:00.000', 2 ),
( 1, '2014-01-01T12:00:00.000', 1 ),
( 2, '2011-01-01T12:00:00.000', 1 )
```

I'd like to get all items with the last status set, in this case

```
1, '2014-01-01T12:00:00.000', 1
2, '2011-01-01T12:00:00.000', 1
3, NULL, NULL
```

What's the most efficient way to solve this?

I tried with a subselect and I get the latest timestamp, but I'm not able to add the status since this field is not included in aggregate-function or group-by. If I add it, the results got grouped by status - logically - but that leads to the fact, that I get too much result-lines and would have to add a further condition / subselect.

You may use the Fiddle-link for created tables and testdata. The second query includes the status-field.

Edit:

adding a further join does the trick, but I doubt that's the way to do it.

```
select 
    i.*
    , d.*
    , s.status
from
    item i
    left join ( select ts = max(ts), itemid from itemstatus group by itemid ) d
        on 1 = 1 
        and i.id = d.itemid
    left join itemstatus s
        on 1 = 1
        and s.itemid = d.itemid
        and s.ts = d.ts
```

See [SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23bcd/2/0) for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` partitioned by `itemid` and ordered by `ts desc` to get the latest registration in `itemstatus` per `itemid`.

```
select I.id,
       S.ts,
       S.status
from item as I
  left outer join (
                  select S.status,
                         S.ts,
                         S.itemid,
                         row_number() over(partition by S.itemid 
                                             order by S.ts desc) as rn
                  from itemstatus as S
                  ) as S
    on I.id = S.itemid and
       S.rn = 1
```